# Rename [sqlserver] tag to [sql-server]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

There's the [sqlserver](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sqlserver) tag. On sister sites it's spelled "[sql-server](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server)". I guess we should change the spelling of the tag here, or at least introduce a synonym?

PS. If we're updating things may as well trust SO and introduce [the synonyms used there](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/synonyms)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The master tag is now [sql-server](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) and I've created [mssql](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mssql) as a synonym. We don't need to introduce every variant: if someone starts typing `ms-sql-server` then `mssql` will show up as a completion, and as for `sql-srever` it shouldn't be in the SO list, we can't catch every typo.